# Spring as parent of a child java project?

Tags: java, spring, maven

I have an existing spring project, and I'd like to develop a different one, reusing some of the business logic. Especially I'd like to combine for the two projects:

- some of the maven pom dependency versions (hibernate, spring, validation, jmx, servlet, connection pooling). Stuff like database url and c3p0-settings could then be customized within each child project, but without having to redefine their setup.
- a basic applicationContext.xml that enables classpath scanning, annotations, transactions, async, schedulers. Ideally, I preconfigure this in some kind of parent project, and all inheriting/child projects could automatically us @Autowired without having to provide additional context.xml files.
- a spring ContextLoaderListener that takes care of shutting down the application orderly (like save terminating all db or currently running webservice requests)
- a spring managed tcp socket gateway that delegates to a service implementation

All this stuff should be reused in my 2nd application. I could now of course copypast/dublicate all stuff that I want to reuse. But that has a significant drawback: I want to be able to change anything in a "shared" content, and it should have impact on both applications.

Eg, if I update the `Spring.version` in maven pom, both apps should get the new version. Also if I change anything within the socket gateway, etc.

Could you advise me how I could achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be overkill for your needs, but this is how I use/have used Maven on systems comprised of many components:

- create a parent POM that declares **ALL** dependencies (both internal and 3rd party) used in the system in a `dependencyManagement` section.
- include common plugins in this same parent POM in either the `plugins` or `pluginManagement` sections.
- each component POM should point to this parent, re-declaring the dependencies each needs in the `dependencies` section.  Importantly, the version can be omitted because it's obtained from the parent POM.
- wire the components together as late as possible in order to maximize the portability of each component.  This normally means creating a common assembly that combines the components and forms a base for environment specific assemblies.

Things to avoid:

- don't use properties for versions, they can be overridden from the command line meaning you can't tell how a deployed artifact was built when looking at Nexus (or a similar repository).
- don't use `modules` within your parent POM, this locks all the modules into the same build and release cycle.  While this might make the *version-control-check-out-and-build* seem easy, it means that you cannot (easily) release a module/component in isolation to the others, for example when you need to patch a bug.

Comment: We did exactly the same. With the exception that we added another level of parent-child maven modules. Like this master -> core master -> feature modules. And for the projects master -> project master -> project modules. While the core is setup with maven modules of each feature the project master is not aggregated into the master but aggregates the project modules.